# dplyr concat columns stored in variable (mutate and non standard evaluation)

Tags: r, nse, dplyr

I would like to concatenate an arbitrary number of columns in a dataframe based on a variable `cols_to_concat`

```
df <- dplyr::data_frame(a = letters[1:3], b = letters[4:6], c = letters[7:9])
cols_to_concat = c("a", "b", "c")
```

To achieve the desired result with this specific value of `cols_to_concat` I could do this:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(concat = paste0(a, b, c))
```

But I need to generalise this, using syntax a bit like this

```
# (DOES NOT WORK)
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(concat = paste0(cols))
```

I'd like to use the new [NSE approach](https://blog.rstudio.org/2017/06/13/dplyr-0-7-0/) of dplyr 0.7.0, if this is appropriate, but can't figure out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `syms` from `rlang`:

```
library(dplyr)
packageVersion('dplyr')
#[1] ‘0.7.0’
df <- dplyr::data_frame(a = letters[1:3], b = letters[4:6], c = letters[7:9])
cols_to_concat = c("a", "b", "c")

library(rlang)
cols_quo <- syms(cols_to_concat)
df %>% mutate(concat = paste0(!!!cols_quo))

# or
df %>% mutate(concat = paste0(!!!syms(cols_to_concat)))

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#       a     b     c concat
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
# 1     a     d     g    adg
# 2     b     e     h    beh
# 3     c     f     i    cfi
```

Answer (score 9):

You can perform this operation using only the `tidyverse` if you'd like to stick to those packages and principles. You can do it by using either `mutate()` or `unite_()`, which comes from the `tidyr` package.

**Using `mutate()`**

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(a = letters[1:3], b = letters[4:6], c = letters[7:9])
cols_to_concat <- c("a", "b", "c")

df %>% mutate(new_col = do.call(paste0, .[cols_to_concat]))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
      a     b     c new_col
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>
1     a     d     g     adg
2     b     e     h     beh
3     c     f     i     cfi
```

**Using `unite_()`**

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% unite_(col='new_col', cols_to_concat, sep="", remove=FALSE)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  new_col     a     b     c
*   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     adg     a     d     g
2     beh     b     e     h
3     cfi     c     f     i
```

---

**EDITED July 2020**

As of **dplyr 1.0.0**, it appears that `across()` and `c_across()` are replacing the underscore verbs (e.g. `unite_`) and scoped variants like `mutate_if()`, `mutate_at()` and `mutate_all()`. Below is an example using that convention. Not the most concise, but still an option that promises to be more extensible.

**Using `c_across()`**

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = letters[1:3], b = letters[4:6], c = letters[7:9])
cols_to_concat <- c("a", "b", "c")

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new_col = paste0(c_across(all_of(cols_to_concat)), collapse=""))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   a     b     c     new_col
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 a     d     g     adg    
#> 2 b     e     h     beh    
#> 3 c     f     i     cfi
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- dplyr::data_frame(a = letters[1:3], b = letters[4:6], c = letters[7:9])

cols_to_concat = lapply(list("a", "b", "c"), as.name)

q <- quos(paste0(!!! cols_to_concat))

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(concat = !!! q)
```

Comment: Having experimented further, the above code works - although I must admit, I'm not sure I fully understand it.  Please add another answer if there's a better way of doing this and I'll accept it...

Comment: Yes, there are many easy ways achieving this such as `df$concat <- do.call(paste0, df[cols_to_concat])` but unfortunately everything these days has to be achieved with the freaking dplyr, so good luck with your quest there.

Comment: Thanks - I did experiment with `do.call` but couldn't figure it out. I hadn't realised you could give it a df, but thinking about it, it's obvious because a df is just a list.  This is clearly a better solution than the tidyverse answer.

Comment: The `tidyverse` provides a convenience pasting function called `unite()`, but it's also possible to use `do.call` and `paste0` inside `mutate`. I've provided both of these solutions as an answer.